# "Substitution replacement not terminated" with variable

Tags: linux, bash, perl

Found this error in other questions, but I can't see how the solutions relate to this.

Assume a file `test` containing:

```
one
twoX
three
```

I can correct `twoX` with:

```
perl -0777 -i -pe 's/twoX/two/igm' test
```

I can make a function to do this:

```
replace_str(){ perl -0777 -i -pe 's/'$2'/'$3'/igm' $1; }
replace_str test twoX two
```

But this fails when the replacement contains a space (possibly other chars):

```
replace_str test two 'two frogs'
Substitution replacement not terminated at -e line 1.
```

The perl line works with the space.  Why not when called in a function?  I've tried with other quotes and e.g. `$(echo two frogs)` (with and without quotes).

Comment: From what script are you calling Perl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you end the string you pass as argument to Perl for your variable expansions. That makes the regex become *two* arguments.

Instead just put the whole regex, including variables, inside double-quotes and the shell should expand the variables properly.

So use `"s/$2/$3/igm"` instead.